# Is it a problem that the stems of my mint cuttings are curling?

Tags: herbs, cuttings, mint

As a minor gardening project in my apartment I've been growing mint, for its robustness and pairing with alcohol.  In my attempt to clone the plant I have and fill another pot, all four of the cuttings I have are curling nearly 180° with a radius of about an inch:

[image: Mint cuttings beginning to root]

Is this just fine to plant with the inch-and-a-half of stem buried and roots nearly coming up on the other side, or, should I try to root cuttings so they stay straight (tips on how?).

Comment: What's that bubbly-looking white stuff on top?

Comment: @ashes999 packing foam ([this stuff](http://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-789/Anti-Static-Foam/1-8-x-12-x-175-Anti-Static-Foam), because I had it laying around)

Comment: Did you plant these with roots facing upwards and how did it go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just plant them as they are once the roots are long in pots large enough to not cramp them. If you keep potting on the mother plant, which you'll need to do because they prefer to be in the ground (roots go down over a foot, and runners spread out 18 inches underground) you can divide that as it gets bigger and get more plants that way.

Comment: Planting with the stem up deep enough so the roots were underground ended up being fine.